# Is MKCoordinateRegion span center to boundary or boundary to boundary?

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit, mkcoordinateregion

Does the span for MKCoordinateRegion represent the distance from the center to each boundary or the distance from boundary to boundary?

If I want to calculate the boundaries of the region to I add/subtract the span from the center or do I need to /2?

lowerLatitude=center-span.latitudeDelta
or
lowerLatitude=center-(span.latitudeDelta/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running this code:

self.mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0.0, 0.0), MKCoordinateSpanMake(23.5, 10.0));

I was able to see as far north as the border of the Western Sahara, and as far south as the Etosha National Park;  as far west as the west cosast of Senegal; and as far east as N'Djamena.

Based on that, and a little time with Google Maps, it appears that the span is a total of 47 degrees north-south, and 20 degrees west-east.

Answer (score 2):

The span is the distance from boundary to boundary. If the most Westerly place you can see is at 10 degrees and the most Eastery is 20 degrees, the `longitudeDelta` will be 10 degrees (span). The center coordinate will have a longitude of 15 degrees (a point, not a span).

To put it another way, the span is twice the distance from the center to the edge. The center is the point half way along both spans.